# Why I get this output by print %f - Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

quick question: why do I get a lot of zeros after the decimal point in the output of this script (value of "total" variable)? (I know how to deal with it and get specific outbut by walk-arounds, but I'm curious why thi iutput looks like this)

Script:

```
prices = {
  "banana" : 4,
  "apple"  : 2,
  "orange" : 1.5,
  "pear"   : 3,
}
stock = {
  "banana" : 6,
  "apple"  : 0,
  "orange" : 32,
  "pear"   : 15,
}

for key in prices:
  print key
  print "price: %s" % prices[key]
  print "stock: %s" % stock[key]
  print

total = 0

for iteration in prices:
  total = total+ prices[iteration] * stock[iteration]

print "total price: %f"%total
```

output:

```
banana
price: 4
stock: 6
apple
price: 2
stock: 0
orange
price: 1.5
stock: 32
pear
price: 3
stock: 15
total price: 117.000000 #********* why so many zeros?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that's the default number of decimal places for the `%f` formatter.

Add a precision specifier; for example, if you only want to display 2 decimal places, use `%.2f`:

```
print "total price: %.2f" % total
```

and the last line of output then becomes

```
total price: 117.00
```

The `.` followed by a digit in the format specification signals the precision specifier. See the [*String Formatting Operations* documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations):

> A conversion specifier contains two or more characters and has the following components, which must occur in this order:
>
> [...]
>
> 5. Precision (optional), given as a `'.'` (dot) followed by the precision. [...]

Further on in the same documentation, the default for `f` is documented under footnote #3:

> The precision determines the number of digits after the decimal point and defaults to 6.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I've read this documentation but apparently didn't understand this point.

Answer (score 0):

you must replace %f by %d or by %i if you dont want zeros and if you want 1 zero you can replace it by %s:

```
>>> print "total price: %d"%total
total price: 117
>>> print "total price: %s"%total
total price: 117.0
>>> print "total price: %f"%total # Like you did
total price: 117.000000
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, but this does not answer my question and I already knew that (like i wrote in the post: "I know how to deal with it and get specific outbut by walk-arounds, but I'm curious why this output looks like this").